# Error while trying to send an account verification email with a dynamic link attached

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

Error while trying to send an account verification email with a dynamic link attached. Appeared after updating Google Services to version 14.3.66

1. Register in firebase auth with email and password:

`firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(login, pass)`

2. Send email verification for firebase user with deep link:

`val settings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
    .setHandleCodeInApp(false)
    .setUrl(BuildConfig.DEEP_LINK)
    .build()
user.sendEmailVerification(settings)`

3. Catch the error in addOnFailureListener with message:

> An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME:Cannot install Android app without providing package name ]

Comment: I have the same thing with my Xamarin Android project. I know that Google recently updated the format of GoogleServices.json. I re-downloaded it, and although it didn't work, it might be all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Android package name in code:

```
val settings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
    .setHandleCodeInApp(false)
    .setAndroidPackageName("com.package.my", true, "1")
    .setUrl(BuildConfig.DEEP_LINK)
    .build();
```